# Android server http Connection

Tags: android, http, server

My android app is connected to my server thorugh http connection.The server will close the connection after 10seconds . But in client side(android) i want to close the connection in 5 seconds neither i receive data or not from the server my android app must close the connection.
when I tried setsotimeout(5000) two things happens
1.The android app is sending request again and again for every 5000milliseconds.
2.It works well in the case when the server closes.
Suggest me some good logic

```
 protected String doInBackground(Object[] params)
    {
        try
        {
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePair = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
        nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("carddata", "this " + "is " + "normal" + "transaction"));
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://127.0.0.1:8080/MyServletProject/DoubleMeServlet");
        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePair));
        HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, 5000);
        httpPost.setParams(httpParameters);
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        Log.d("Http Post Response:", response.toString());
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        dsds = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
    } catch (Exception e)
    {
        if (e.toString().equals("java.net.SocketTimeoutException"))
        {
            dsds=e.toString();

        }
```

Comment: 'The server will close the connection after 10seconds'. Nonsense. The server will close the connection as soon as he send the reply. 'in client side(android) i want to close the connection in 5 seconds'. Nonsense too as the client will close the connection as soon as the reply is received. '127.0.0.1'. That will not work unless you have your server on your device. What is it what you want and why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I was you, I would create a layer between by http client and my app. Every time a request is made, it restarts a 5000ms timer to kill the connection.

Comment: thanks for ur suggestion @Perroloco i updated the question with my code,can u make a look and tell whether my implementation is correct or wrong?